# Jupyter notebook bug

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run this in jupyter notebook:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
heights = [[1.6], [1.65], [1.7], [1.73], [1.8]]
weights = [[60], [65], [72.3], [75], [80]]
model.fit(X=heights, y=weights)
```

It says "Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." and never runs. I have no idea why this happens, and if anyone has any ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: What happens when you run it outside of a notebook?

Comment: Just tried it it says: OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_affinity.cpp(414).
OMP: Hint Please submit a bug report with this message, compile and run commands used, and machine configuration info including native compiler and operating system versions. Faster response will be obtained by including all program sources. For information on submitting this issue, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

Comment: So it sounds like it's not a jupyter bug, to me

Comment: How did you resolve it?